# Sql request with php : select posts where there is a youtube link

Tags: php, sql, regex, youtube

I tried to make a sql request with php which selects posts where there is a youtube link but it doesn't works.

This is what I did :

```
$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8', 'root', '');
$motif='#http(?:s?)://(?:www\.)?youtu(?:be\.com/watch\?v=|\.be/)([\w\-\_]+)(&(amp;)?[\w\?=‌​]*)?#';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post REGEXP :motif";
$params = array(':motif'=>$motif);
$search_for_yt_links = $bdd->prepare($sql);
$search_for_yt_links->execute($params);

$result = $search_for_yt_links->fetch();
var_dump($result);
```

I get this result :

```
false
```

This shuld be :

```
array (size=1)
  'post' => string 'Look at my new video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y2Xef0CnUYA. Awesome ?' (length=75)
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work. 
Can you help me ?

Thanks.

Comment: print the `$sql` ??

Comment: Please specify DB engine and specify current result and expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex detects full links and short ones (youtu.be)

```
"/\s*[a-zA-Z\/\/:\.]*youtu(be.com\/watch\?v=|.be\/)([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)([a-zA-Z0-9\/\*\-\_\?\&\;\%\=\.]*)/i"
```

Comment: I think it finally worked rght? this regex works awesome for me

Answer (score 0):

Try this regexp. 
`'http(s)?://(www\.)?youtu(be\.com/watch\\?v=|\.be/)([[:alnum:]]+)'`

Comment: this doesn't with links as :

Comment: it does.. if it's about the missing http(s)://, it can be omitted easily like this `(http(s)?://)?`. 
Try to use the query directly into the database (console, phpmyadmin etc.) to see if you get the results. There might be problem somewhere else. EDIT: Why there is "#" in your regexp?